# MVC3 - Why doesn't the GET method in controller get called when rendering partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, get, partial-views

I created a partial view, abc in my Views/Home

added this to my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult abc()
{
return View();
}
```

and I call the partial view like this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/abc.cshtml")
```

I'm able to see the partial view but the controller method does not get called. How can I render a partial view and call the controller get method?

Comment: You could pass the model to the PartialView (or via ViewBag)... to avoid needing the abc controller (the logic will be in the parent controller). This way is a bit messy but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) method (on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721299.aspx)):

View:

```
@Html.Action("abc", "Home")
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult abc()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A controller renders a view.  You clearly have a controller that is rendering your parent view (the one that has the `@Html.Partial` in it.  Partial simply merges the partial view with the current view, so no additional controller is accessed.

Think about it.  You are not actually specifying an action, now are you?  You're only specifying a view.  Views cannot be rendered by themselves.

What you want is `@Html.Action()`, which renders based on a controller action.

Comment: Great, thanks I misunderstood PartialViews. I was treating them like Views too.

Comment: Partial Views are like views.  There's no real difference.  It's just that Partial merges one view with another.  Views are templates, they have nothing to do with controllers.  So when you render a partial in your view, it's just merging two templates.  No controller access is performed